# AppCompat MODE_NIGHT_AUTO event listener

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm using AppCompat MODE_NIGHT_AUTO in Android app in order to automatically switch between day and night. It works great. Now I'm looking for the **event listener** which fires when automatic switch between day/night occurs (i.e. on sunset/sunrise).

The reason why I need it: I want to save the state of my app, so on the event of activity recreation due of day/night change I can restore the state. Please note, that I can (of course) constantly save the state, but I don't want to do so, because I don't want to keep the state in case of simple app restart, only when day/night change occurs.